# QWinEventNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread

Tags: c++, qt, usb, dongle, qextserialport

I am trying to open my Huwawei USB dongle using "QextSerialPort".

My PORT details are as follows

```
Port Name:
Product ID:
Physical Name: \Device\000000ca
Vendor Id:
Friend Name:  SB

Port Name:
Product ID:?
Physical Name: \Device\USBPDO-10
Vendor Id: ?
Friend Name:  TH

Port Name: COM3
Product ID:
Physical Name: \Device\BthModem0
Vendor Id:
Friend Name: Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM3)

Port Name: COM4
Product ID:
Physical Name: \Device\BthModem2
Vendor Id:
Friend Name: Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM4)

Port Name: COM5
Product ID:
Physical Name: \Device\BthModem1
Vendor Id:
Friend Name: Standard Modem over Bluetooth link

Port Name: COM6
Product ID:?
Physical Name: \Device\000000e2
Vendor Id: ?
Friend Name: HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Application Interface (COM6)

Port Name: COM7
Product ID:?
Physical Name: \Device\000000e0
Vendor Id: ?
Friend Name: HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Modem

Port Name: COM8
Product ID:?
Physical Name: \Device\000000e3
Vendor Id: ?
Friend Name: HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G PC UI Interface (COM8)
```

I trying to open MY USB dongle, so I can send SMS. Following is my code for opening

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qdebug.h>


int main()
{
    QextSerialPort *port = new QextSerialPort("COM7");
    port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    cout << port->isOpen();

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

When I run this code, what I get is

```
QWinEventNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread 
1
```

This shows the port id Open, but what about that message? Does that means I can't proceed with other code? I want to know this before I code anything else.

Comment: And, am I calling to the correct port? I am very new to QT and USB programming'

Comment: Any reason for not using QtSerialPort (official Qt 5 add-on), btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you need to create a `QApplication`, without it many things like events and signals/slots won't work:

```
int main()
{
    QApplication app;

    QextSerialPort *port = new QextSerialPort("COM7");
    port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    cout << port->isOpen();

    system("pause");

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: ha, I need to type faster :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But which header file should I import? I can't find "qapplication.h"

Comment: If you're not creating a GUI application, use [QCoreApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html) instead

Comment: @Yohan, `#include <QApplication>` should work. If not, try `#include <QCoreApplication>` as suggested by thuga.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I had to use QCoreApplication header with it's implementation. Anyway, even in GUI, I can't find <QApplication>

Comment: @Yohan QApplication is part of the QtGui module. You need to include it in your .pro file. Qt += gui. Make sure you don't have Qt -= gui in your .pro file.